# Far cry game is not displaying its video

Tags: pc, far-cry

I have downloaded and installed the far cry (game) but now when I run farcry.exe file it shows me an error "Unsupported signal . Check your output device " and I can still hear the background music of the game . So how can I resolve this issue regarding the video display?

Comment: Which far cry game? Are your graphics cards drivers up to date?

Comment: I am talking about far cry one . Other far crys won't work on my pc

Comment: My comp specs r .32 bit windows 7 with 4GB RAM .no I don't have a graphic card

Answer (score 2):

Going to tackle a few things here, in hopes of solving your problem as easily as possible (this could actually be a few things)

### Integrated vs Dedicated Graphics

First and foremost, **you have to have a graphic card or your computer would not work**. When we talk graphic cards for game support, we refer to the **dedicated graphics**, which is the extra part you put in specifically for handling graphics. By default, you will be relying on **integrated graphics**, which is almost never reliable for games. That said, hard ware has come a long way - **Your integrated graphics may still be capable of running Far Cry**.

### System Requirements

These are the system requirements for Far Cry, as listed at [systemrequirementslab.com](http://www.systemrequirementslab.com/CYRI/Requirements/far-cry/10247?p=r):

- **CPU**:  Pentium III or Athlon 1GHz+
- **RAM**: 256MB+
- **OS**: Windows (98SE, ME, 2000, XP)
- **GPU**: DirectX 9.0b compliant with 64MB+ RAM *(recommends GeForce2+ or Radeon 8500+)*
- **HDD**: 4GB+

We need 64MB of RAM and DirectX 9.0b compatibility for graphics. Matching your hardware to the required DirectX version is a good way to gauge how suitable a graphics system is, as DirectX is the "middle man" between the game and your graphics hardware.

### Meeting the Operating System Requirements

There are actually two things here that you are missing: the dedicated graphics, and the operating system. While having as faster processor, or more RAM does not pose a problem, a newer operating system will not necessarily speak the same language as its predecessor, often presenting problems in running older games. Luckily, Windows 7 and 8 both have compatibility mode.

Right click on the icon and go to properties.

You should see "Compatibility" as a tab option along the top. Click on it.

You can run compatibility troubleshooter for your computers best estimate, but if you toggle on **Run this program in compatibility mode for:** and select any of the Windows versions listed above, you might find the game runs.

### Meeting the Graphics Requirements

Your system will be running off an integrated card, but I have had integrated graphics run a game requiring 256MB of dedicated memory. And from a quick look, Intel Integrated Graphics can currently support up to DirectX 10.

I work a lot with computers, both in game developing and sales, but my experience may still be with models that are newer then yours. If worse comes to worst, you may still need to get yourself a dedicated graphic card.

**If you are using a tower**, a card that supports Far Cry would be inexpensive, as hardware has come a long way since 2004.

**If you are using an All in One or a Laptop/Notebook**, you are looking to upgrade your entire setup, as parts are not as designed to "slot in and out", so upgrading one part will incur much higher service cost.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the only way to "resolve the issue" is to **have** a video card (aka. graphics card).

System requirements for Far Cry I found on [systemrequirementslab.com](http://www.systemrequirementslab.com/CYRI/Requirements/far-cry/10247?p=r) list as a requirement

> **Video Card:** DirectX 9.0b compliant video card with 64 MB RAM (GeForce2+ / Radeon 8500+)

In general, almost all modern games require a graphics card of some description. Some games (mostly 2D) will work fine with just an integrated card, but especially the 3D ones will require a dedicated craphics card.

The error you are seeing is most likely generated not by your computer, by your display when your computer stops outputting video signal. Most likely because the game is trying to put the video signal through a graphics card that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

This game work with 1900x1200 resolution. So first change your pc resolution.and if you are using Nvidia than try to use the HDMI port of your pc for display.

If you are using Nvidia or amd. Uninstall the driver with the help of display driver uninstaller(ddu) .Uninstall in safe mode recommended.after uninstalling restart your pc. Remove the pcsplash from game folder.restart pc. Open game. Close it. Restore pcsplash from recycle bin. Install the display driver of your graphic card. Play the game in administration.

For pcsplash. Go to game installed path. Go to bin in the folder of game. You will find a pcsplash named application.